# Accessing ConnectedComponent.WrappedComponent from composed connect to ensure inferred types are propagated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recompose

Very much looking for some help on this

Libs used: recompose, react-redux

**The issue:**
When composing redux's `connect` with other HOC's with `compose` I'm losing types within compose and trying to access from a text context `ConnectedComponent.WrappedComponent` throws a type error:  `'Property 'WrappedComponent' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'`.

**The Code**

```
import React, { Fragment, SFC } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { branch, renderComponent, compose } from 'recompose';
import { RootState } from '../../types/state';

interface StateProps {
  foo?: boolean;
}

const Component: SFC<StateProps> = ({ children }) => <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>;

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  foo: state.foo
});

export default compose<StateProps, {}>(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  branch<StateProps>(
    ({ foo }) => !initialised,
    renderComponent(() => <div className="branched" />)
  )
)(Component);
```

Then Accessing the wrapped component errors as the types are not carried through:

```
const Gateway = ConnectedGateway.WrappedComponent;
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ->'Property 'WrappedComponent' does not exist on type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'
```

There are a few solutions I've found that seem to work, changing the composition for example

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(compose(
  // Stuff Here
)(Component))
```

Keeps the types, but shouldn't be necessary as from a FP standpoint it's exactly the same as `compose(connect, branch)(Component)`

The other is extending `ComponentClass` and exporting `as unknown as IComponent` which feels like a lot of hoops to jump through:

```
import React, { Fragment, SFC, ComponentClass } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { branch, renderComponent, compose } from 'recompose';
import { RootState } from '../../types/state';

interface StateProps {
  foo?: boolean;
}

interface IComponent extends ComponentClass<StateProps, {}> {
  WrappedComponent: SFC<StateProps>;
}

const Component: SFC<StateProps> = ({ children }) => <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>;

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  foo: state.foo
});

export default (compose<StateProps, {}>(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  branch<StateProps>(({ foo }) => !foo, renderComponent(() => <div className="branched" />))
)(Component) as unknown) as IComponent;
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**EDIT: BETTER SOLUTION**

You can cast it to the correct type using `ConnectedComponentClass` which simplifies the typing a lot.

```
import React, { Fragment, SFC, ComponentClass } from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedComponentClass } from 'react-redux';
import { branch, renderComponent, compose } from 'recompose';
import { RootState } from '../../types/state';

interface StateProps {
  foo?: boolean;
}

const Component: SFC<StateProps> = ({ children }) => <Fragment>{children}</Fragment>;

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps => ({
  foo: state.foo
});

export default compose<StateProps, {}>(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  branch<StateProps>(({ foo }) => !foo, renderComponent(() => <div className="branched" />))
)(Component) as ConnectedComponentClass<SFC<StateProps>, {}>;
```